# Tabulator v5 tooltip: cell.getData is not a function?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Using Tabulator v5 with Laravel (v8).

In the tooltip of a column I want to refer to another property.

This used to work in v4:

**resources/js/app.js**

```js
import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables';
window.Tabulator = Tabulator;
```

**table.blade.php**

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
...
  columns: [
    { title:'test', field:'test',
      tooltip: function(cell) {
        console.log("cell:", cell ) // ColumnObject (?)
        console.log("field:", cell.getField() ) // "test"
        console.log("cells:", cell.getCells() ) // empty
        console.log("data:", cell.getData() ) // error: no such function
        //return cell.getData().someProperty
      },
    },
  ],
...
})
```

Now I get an error in the console:

```
cell: Proxy {_column: Column$1, type: 'ColumnComponent'}
field: test
cells: []
The column component does not have a getData function, have you checked that you have the correct Tabulator module installed?
```

[Tabulator's tooltip documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/format#tooltips) states the argument is a [CellComponent](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/components#component-cell) but it actually is a [ColumnComponent](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/components#component-column)? And/but `getCells()` does not return the cells?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getCells` function on a [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/components#component-cell), you would need to get the [Row Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/components#component-row) to call that function.

So your code should read:

```js
console.log("cells:", cell.getRow().getCells())
```

Comment: It's not right. With Tabulator v4 this work well but Tabulator v5 tooltip seems not working.

Comment: The tooltip functionality was completely replaced in version 5 with fully custom tooltips. Checkout the docs for full details of the upgrade